# How to configure embedded jetty base resource for servlet in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot

How do I configure embedded jetty base resource for servlet in Spring Boot?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html) contains pretty good piece of information regarding embedded containers. In order to have Jetty as your Embedded container all what you need to do is just to update boot dependencies. All other configuration should pretty standard for Servlet/Spring MVC application.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The solution turns out to be putting my static resources including gwt policy files under Spring Boot's default locations serving static contents (i.e. src/main/webapp, public/, and static/) Then, Spring Boot will set the resource base during initialization.